# Node.js: Call properties with dashes (-)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to call a property which has a dash (message-id).

msg.message-id is not the solution because it is seen as 2 different words. How do I call 'message-id'?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
msg["message-id"]
```

You can access properties using the array access notation (but with the string instead of an integer).